# How can I use for .. of loops in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

```
//No issues in below:
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (let i of a) {
    document.write('<br />' + i); //1 2 3 4 5
}
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

//No issues in below either
function add(...numbers: number[]): number {
    let temp: number = 0;
    for (var i: number = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        temp += numbers[i];
    }
    return temp;
}

let result: number = add(1,5,8); 
document.body.innerHTML = `Result = ${result}`; //Result = 14
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

// Hmm! Undefined
function add(...numbers: number[]): number {
    let temp: number = 0;
    for (let i of numbers) {
        temp += numbers[i];
    }
    return temp;
}

let result: number = add(1,5,8); 
document.body.innerHTML = `Result = ${result}`; // Result = NaN
```

I am trying to use new "of" for loops in TypeScript.
However, not working as I expected. For example, in last try I am getting "NaN" value when I was expected to get 14. 
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you have code which you forgot, you can simply [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34362214/edit) your question to include it in the question. Note that TypeScript compiles to JavaScript. How it compiles depends on the target you give to the compiler. Check out the chart [here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) and note that some uses of for..of loops are not supported by TypeScript.

Comment: New to this. Thanks for info and the tip Mike.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for (... of ...)` syntax yields the *actual elements of the array* and not their *indices*. Therefore the proper JavaScript syntax is simply:

```ts
function add(...numbers: number[]): number {
    let sum = 0;
    for (const i of numbers) {
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Of course, since `numbers` is an array ES6 also allows you to do this with the one-liner:

```ts
const add = (...numbers: number[]) => numbers.reduce((x, y) => x + y, 0);
```

In fact in terms of performance, the latter might be slightly more easy for the VM to optimize, although the VM might not optimize it until `add()` has been called many times and determined to be a hotspot in the code. But of course your decision about which you adopt depends on whether you have a team who is comfortable with folds like the above.

Comment: and for TS you'd have to make sure to typedef the source item eg `numbers`, not the element in the for loop `i` since TS doesn't allow that.